# Why do we pass second parameter in angular.bootstrap() as an array?

Tags: angularjs, ng-app

I am beginner of angularJs , we can initialize the application by manually by using bootstraping concept.
such as angular.bootstrap(DOMELEMENT,[MODULENAME])
My question is if we pass multiple values in second parameter like ['App1','App2','App3'] but still we have only target DOM element that we are passing in first parameter ,so what is the use of array in this case ,please someone guide me i have go through the docs as well but didn't my answer.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

please help me understand ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module contains controllers, directives, filters, services, etc.

If you want your app to contain all the controllers, directives etc. of 2 separate modules A and B, then you can pass these two modules in the array.

Or you can create a third module C which has the A and B modules as dependencies, and pass only the module C to `bootstrap()`.

Comment: Thanks for answering ,it make sense :)